# MySQL nested SELECTs

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, pivot-table

I'm in over my head with this query. I have a table which looks something like this (simplified):

```
Date         Weight kg
-------------------
2012-04-16     12.4
2012-04-17      9.6
2012-04-16      5.4
2012-04-18      2.8
2012-04-16      4.5
...             ...
```

I want the query to return this result:

```
Week.no.  <3kg  3-7kg   >7kg
----------------------------
16         2.8    9.9   22.0
...        ...    ...   ....
```

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT *, CONCAT(WEEK(`Date`)) AS Week, SUM(`Weight`) AS TotalWeight,
   (SELECT SUM(`Weight`) FROM tbl_fangster WHERE `Weight` < 3 AND
   `Date` >= '2012-04-01 00:00:00' AND `Date` <= '2012-04-30 00:00:00'
   AND `Species` = 'Salmon' ) AS SumSmall
FROM tbl_fangster
WHERE `Date` >= '2012-04-01 00:00:00'
AND `Date` <= '2012-04-30 00:00:00'
AND `Species` = 'Salmon'
GROUP BY CONCAT(WEEK(`Date`))
```

but SumSmall returns the same number on each row, namely the total SumSmall rather than the SumSmall for each week. I've tried to copypaste my GROUP clause into the subquery, but it didn't work.

Comment: Your sub-query will need to specify the interval for that week only.

Comment: Your subquery isn't dependent on any of the fields in the container query, so it'll return the same values every time. You'd want what's known as a correlated subquery, where the subquery uses a field from the parent query to do its work: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a CASE statement to handle the various conditions.

```
SELECT *, CONCAT(WEEK(`Date`)) AS Week, SUM(`Weight`) AS TotalWeight,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Weight < 3 THEN Weight ELSE 0 END) AS SumSmall,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Weight >= 3 AND Weight <= 7 THEN Weight ELSE 0 END) AS SumMedium,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Weight > 7 THEN Weight ELSE 0 END) AS SumLarge
FROM tbl_fangster
WHERE `Date` >= '2012-04-01 00:00:00'
AND `Date` <= '2012-04-30 00:00:00'
AND `Species` = 'Salmon'
GROUP BY CONCAT(WEEK(`Date`))
```

Comment: Joe, I didn't even know the CASE clause existed. I've been tearing my hair off for a couple of hours now. You just saved me from lifelong baldness! Thanks! :D